# Using One Function To Create Two Different Shortcodes

Tags: functions, shortcode, query

To populate a player rollcall, an extensive query pulls data from tables in my external MySQL database. Part of this also extracts the player(s) who a) made the most appearances and b) scored the most goals. For a couple of reasons, I now want to move this into `functions.php` and output the most appearances AND most goals as separate shortcodes from one function. Is this possible? I've only managed to do one or the other at the moment.

The shortcodes I'm aiming to create are `[seasonapps]` and `[seasongoals]`. And the intention is that the first outputs the player who made the total number of appearances, while the second outputs the player who scored the most goals.

The function currently looks like this (appreciate it's a lot – have truncated parts for brevity):

```
function seasonapps ( $atts ){
    global $boroguideDB;
    $seasonID = get_the_title();
    $appsetup = $boroguideDB->get_results("SELECT re.date, re.venue, re.comp, re.opponent, re.score, re.att, ce.name, ce.ID, re.agg, re.ID, se.blurb, se.ID, re.season, re.compkey FROM resultengine re INNER JOIN clubengine ce ON re.opponent=ce.ID INNER JOIN seasonengine se ON se.season=re.season WHERE (re.season='".$seasonID."') ORDER BY re.date ASC", ARRAY_A);
    foreach($appsetup as $row) {
        $myHashMap = array();
        if (!function_exists('processAppsUpdate'))   {      
            function processAppsUpdate($myHashMap, $row) {
                $id = $row['game'];
                if (array_key_exists($id, $myHashMap)) {
                    $tempApps = $myHashMap[$id]['apps'];
                    $myHashMap[$id]['apps'] = $tempApps + $row['count'];
                    $tempTotal = $myHashMap[$id]['totalapps'];
                    $myHashMap[$id]['totalapps'] = $tempTotal + $row['count'];
                } else {
                    $tempArray = array();
                    $tempArray[$id] = $id;
                    $tempArray['fname'] = $row['first'];
                    $tempArray['lname'] = $row['last'];
                    $tempArray['playerID'] = $row['players'];     
                    $tempArray['totalapps'] = $row['count'];
                    $tempArray['apps'] = $row['count'];
                    $tempArray['subs'] = 0;
                    $tempArray['unused'] = 0;     
                    $tempArray['goals'] = 0;
                    $tempArray['yellow'] = 0;
                    $tempArray['red'] = 0;        
                    $tempArray['playerid'] = $id;
                    $myHashMap[$id] = $tempArray;
                }
                return $myHashMap;
            }                   
            function processGoalsUpdate($myHashMap, $row) {
                $id = $row['game'];
                if (array_key_exists($id, $myHashMap)) {
                    $tempApps = $myHashMap[$id]['goals'];
                    $myHashMap[$id]['goals'] = $tempApps + $row['count'];
                } else {
                    $tempArray = array();
                    $tempArray[$id] = $id;
                    $tempArray['fname'] = $row['first'];
                    $tempArray['lname'] = $row['last'];
                    $tempArray['playerID'] = $row['players'];         
                    $tempArray['apps'] = 0;
                    $tempArray['unused'] = 0;     
                    $tempArray['goals'] = $row['count'];
                    $tempArray['yellow'] = 0;
                    $tempArray['red'] = 0;    
                    $tempArray['subs'] = 0;
                    $tempArray['playerid'] = $id;
                    $myHashMap[$id] = $tempArray;
                }
                return $myHashMap;
            }

            $PL1 = $boroguideDB->get_results("SELECT mt.ID1 as game,pe.firstname as first,pe.lastname as last,pe.ID as players,COUNT(*) as count FROM matchteam mt RIGHT JOIN playerengine pe ON mt.ID1=pe.ID RIGHT JOIN resultengine re ON mt.ID=re.ID WHERE (mt.ID1!='9998') AND (mt.ID1!='0') AND (mt.ID!='1624') AND (mt.ID!='1638') AND (mt.ID!='225') AND (mt.ID!='248') AND (re.season='".$seasonID."') GROUP BY mt.ID1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", ARRAY_A);
            foreach($PL1 as $row) {
                $myHashMap = processAppsUpdate($myHashMap, $row);
            }
            $PL2 = $boroguideDB->get_results("SELECT mt.ID2 as game,pe.firstname as first,pe.lastname as last,pe.ID as players,COUNT(*) as count FROM matchteam mt RIGHT JOIN playerengine pe ON mt.ID2=pe.ID RIGHT JOIN resultengine re ON mt.ID=re.ID WHERE (mt.ID2!='9998') AND (mt.ID2!='0') AND (mt.ID!='1624') AND (mt.ID!='1638') AND (mt.ID!='225') AND (mt.ID!='248') AND (re.season='".$seasonID."') GROUP BY mt.ID2 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", ARRAY_A);
            foreach($PL2 as $row) {
                $myHashMap = processAppsUpdate($myHashMap, $row);
            }

...

            $S1 = $boroguideDB->get_results("SELECT ms.S1 as game,pe.firstname as first,pe.lastname as last,pe.ID as players,COUNT(*) as count FROM matchscorer ms RIGHT JOIN playerengine pe ON ms.S1=pe.ID RIGHT JOIN resultengine re ON ms.ID=re.ID WHERE (ms.S1!='0') AND (ms.ID!='1624') AND (ms.ID!='1638') AND (ms.ID!='225') AND (ms.ID!='248') AND (re.season='".$seasonID."') GROUP BY ms.S1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", ARRAY_A);
            foreach($S1 as $row) {
                $myHashMap = processGoalsUpdate($myHashMap, $row);
            }
            $S2 = $boroguideDB->get_results("SELECT ms.S2 as game,pe.firstname as first,pe.lastname as last,pe.ID as players,COUNT(*) as count FROM matchscorer ms RIGHT JOIN playerengine pe ON ms.S2=pe.ID RIGHT JOIN resultengine re ON ms.ID=re.ID WHERE (ms.S2!='0') AND (ms.ID!='1624') AND (ms.ID!='1638') AND (ms.ID!='225') AND (ms.ID!='248') AND (re.season='".$seasonID."') GROUP BY ms.S2 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", ARRAY_A);
            foreach($S2 as $row) {
                $myHashMap = processGoalsUpdate($myHashMap, $row);
            }

...

            $maxTotalApps = 0;
            $maxTotalApps = 0;
            $maxTotalAppsPlayer = "";
            $maxGoals = 0;
            $maxGoalsPlayer = "";
            foreach (array_keys($myHashMap) as $hashMapKey) {
                $totapps = isset($myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['totalapps']) ? $myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['totalapps'] : '';
                if ($totapps > $maxTotalApps) {
                    $maxTotalApps = $myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['totalapps'];
                    $maxTotalAppsPlayer = $myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['fname']." ".$myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['lname'];
                } else if ($totapps == $maxTotalApps) {
                    $maxTotalAppsPlayer = $maxTotalAppsPlayer." / ".$myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['fname']." ".$myHashMap[$hashMapKey]['lname'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $maxTotalAppsPlayer." - ".$maxTotalApps;
}
add_shortcode( 'seasonapps', 'seasonapps' );
```

For the second shortcode, I have got no further than – but see it's a separate function from the other and therefore isn't making the relationship with the query in the first:

```
function seasongoals ( $atts ){
    return $maxGoalsPlayer." - ".$maxGoals; 
}
add_shortcode( 'seasongoals', 'seasonapps' );
```

Can the two be combined? I've referred to other articles such as [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334250/multible-shortcodes-for-differnt-values-with-one-function) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329869/multiple-do-shortcodecontent-within-one-shortcode) but not sure the questions being asked are the same as this one.

And, if a second shortcode output can be generated from the original function, can a third or fourth etc.?

Comment: Not 100% sure how to answer you, but would this maybe help? `function seasongoals ( $atts ){ $return = seasonapps( $atts ); return $return; }` or just register a new shortcode using that same function, that's allowed.

Comment: Not sure how to go about implementing the first suggestion within the broader code? For the second suggestion, am I right in thinking registering a new shortcode would look like this `function seasongoals ( $atts ){return $maxGoalsPlayer;} add_shortcode( 'seasongoals', 'seasonapps' )` - tried this, but it didn't output anything. Instead, displayed an Undeclared Variable warning for `$maxTotalAppsPlayer` from the original shortcode.

Comment: If you want to register the same function as two shortcodes you can call add_shortcode twice. `add_shortcode( 'first', 'seasonapps' ); add_shortcode( 'second', 'seasonapps' );`, does that help?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Have tried different ways of calling add_shortcode twice in that sense, but the second shortcode still didn't output anything - and again displayed that Undeclared Variable warning. My understanding would also be that calling add_shortcode twice here would theoretically return the same value as each other - rather than two distinct values derived from the function. Or am I wrong on that?

Comment: There's a few places your code isn't working as expected. The `processAppsUpdate` & `processGoalsUpdate` shouldn't be nested within a parent function. That structure would work in javascript, but not php. $maxTotalAppsPlayer is undefined because it's defined within a child-scope.

Comment: Ah, OK – thanks for pointing that out. Shall go back to the drawing board.